# In the angular 10 undecorated class migration, how should I handle the case where a base class is inherited by Directives and Injectables?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

In the angular 10 migration, it says that classes that use angular features should have a decorator, but how should I handle the case where it's a base class shared by Injectables and Directives (because it only implements `OnDestroy`)? Can I use `@Directive` and `@Injectable` on the same class, or should i split the class into 2 separate classes, one to be inherited by directives, and one by injectables?

It appears to build just fine like this, but is this a problem:

```
@Injectable()
@Directive()
// tslint:disable-next-line:directive-class-suffix
export class SomeBaseClass implements OnDestroy
```

links:
https://v10.angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes
https://v10.angular.io/guide/migration-injectable

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation page](https://v10.angular.io/guide/migration-injectable) you have shared:

> However, classes which are already decorated with @Pipe, @Component or @Directive do not need both decorators. The existing class decorator already instructs the compiler to generate the needed information.

Base classes for *injectables* does not require any annotation. However, *injectables* does not have the lifecycle hooks that comes with directives and components. See [the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-service-lifecycle?file=src/app/base.ts)

Comment: I guess I'm blind. I read most of that page, but didn't notice that part. Ok, then I'm assuming that it's fine to have a normal `@Injectable()` service inherit from a `@Directive()` base class?

Comment: Yes, it is ok. But if you are using lifecycle hooks (onInit, onDestroy etc.) they won't work for the injectable.

Comment: Well that defeats the purpose of the inheritance then, because that's what it was being used for in previous versions and it worked fine.

Comment: For instance, an `@Injectable`, when provided to a component, would have its `ngOnDestroy()` function called when the component was destroyed

Comment: A base-class can still have its ngOnDestroy, el al. called if you call this.super() once you hit the component implementing the base class. As long as you hit a `@Directive()`, or a `@Component()` somewhere in your hierarchy. We do exactly this for leaflet map layers.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen Yes, I tried this in the stackblitz example linked above, and it worked fine. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "somewhere in your hierarchy", because you don't have to inherit from `@Directive` or `@Component` for `ngOnDestroy` to get invoked in the class.